# How do I integrate BIRT logging into application logging?

Tags: java, log4j, birt

I'm developing a web application using Spring Framework, Hibernate, and Wicket. I've integrated the BIRT runtime engine as the reporting component, but I have a problem with logging. Every other component in the application eventually delivers its log messages to `log4j`. I have a single `log4j` configuration file which allows me to adjust the detail of each component.

BIRT, however, wants me to call `setLogConfig()` with a directory name argument. The first problem is that this gives me yet another filesystem path to place in the application configuration, and the second problem is that I can't follow BIRT logs using the same tools that follow the rest of the application.

Does anybody have a solution to integrate BIRT logging into `log4j`, or some other application wide logging system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quiet simple: yes.

BIRT uses the java util logging, but you can write a simple log handler redirecting to log4j. I could repeat it, but the solution is still offered in the [BIRT-FAQ in Eclipse-Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Deployment#Q%3a_Can_I_use_Log4j_with_BIRT.3F)

Comment: I've just updated to BIRT 3.7, and I can confirm this works. I've added my logging config using this recipe in my main routine: `LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration( MyRuntime.class.getResourceAsStream("loghandler.properties"))`